# <<use>> or <<create>> relationship in program code

Tags: oop, design-patterns, uml, class-diagram, class-relationship

I can't figure out what a <<use>> or <<create>> relationship looks like in program code? Can someone give me an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `«Create»` dependency says that an object of one class creates instances of another one. A typical example is the [factory pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). The wikipedia article shows both the UML class diagram with create dependency and an example code.

The `«use»` dependency tells that objects of one class uses instances of another class and therefore need to know about that other class. This [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53479892/3723423) explains all the details. A typical example is when that some operations (methods) have parameters of the type of the other class:

```
 class B { ... }
 class A {
   public doSomething(B b) { ... }
 }
```

[image]